# How to map data between tables when they are connected by foreign key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for **resources** which contains resources like case studies, whitepapers, webinars etc.

It has one to many relationship with another table **case_study_blocks**. So there is a foreign key **caseStudyId** in the **case_study_blocks** table, which points to case studies in the **resources** table.

I want to move all the case studies to a separate table **case_studies**, but to do that I'll also have to update the foreign key reference in the **case_study_blocks** table and make all the records there point to the newly generated unique ids in **case_study** table.

What is the correct way to migrate the complete data while preserving the relationship?

One way I can think of:

- Drop foreign key constraint on **case_study_blocks**
- Add new foreign key constraint on the **caseStudyId** column, pointing to the id column in case_studies table
- But now how do I map the existing **case_study_blocks** correctly to the new IDs in **case_studies** table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the steps as follows:

- Copy the relevant data (related to case studies) to the new `case_studies` table, including the original ID value -- which could be called `oldCaseStudyId` -- so that the `case_studies` table will have the newly generated ID (`caseStudyId`), *and* the original ID in a separate `oldCaseStudyId` column. The latter can be dropped when all is done.
- Drop the existing foreign key constraint on `case_study_blocks.caseStudyId`
- Perform the update of the `caseStudyId` values by the mapping that is now available in `case_studies` (it has both the old and new ID values). The SQL statement could look something like this:

  ```
  update case_study_blocks
  inner join case_studies on case_studies.oldCaseStudyId = case_study_blocks.caseStudyId
  set case_study_blocks.caseStudyId = case_studies.caseStudyId;
  ```
- Create the replacing foreign key constraint on `case_study_blocks.caseStudyId`
- Delete the original rows from `resources` that relate to case studies
- Drop the column `case_study_blocks.oldCaseStudyId`